# Convert list to json values - python

Tags: python, json

I'm creating a list of values, which get exported as a text file. I'm then later re-importing the same text file. The issue is I'm trying to utilise json when handling the string values to make it easier to read the data.

I'm currently getting a lot of spaces when reading the text file though.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import json


date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

item = 'bike'

price = '10'

new_item = [date, item, price]


data = []

data.append(new_item)

jsondata = json.dumps(data)


with open("file.txt", 'w') as output:
        for row in jsondata:               
            output.write(str(row) + '\n')

#re-import txt file
df = pd.read_json("file.txt")
df.columns = ["Datetime", "Item", "Cost"]
```

Out:

```
                                            Datetime                      Item            Cost
0  \r\n2\r\n0\r\n2\r\n4\r\n-\r\n0\r\n2\r\n-\r\n0\...  \r\nb\r\ni\r\nk\r\ne\r\n  \r\n1\r\n0\r\n
```

Intended:

```
                Datetime  Item Cost
0    2020-02-06 17:31:15  bike   10
```

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do with `for row in jsondata:`. You do understand `jsondata` is a string right? Iterating over a string gives you **individual characters** of it. So you're just printing one character per line. It's weird `pd.read_json` didn't just throw an error on reading that file.

Comment: In your own words, whre the code says `for row in jsondata:`, what do you think this should mean? What do you expect `jsondata` to look like at this point in the code? (Did you try to check? Was it like you expected)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsondata` is a string generated by `json.dumps()`. So if you do `for row in jsondata:` you iterate over the string, character by character.

You can simply use `json.dump(data, output)` to write `data` to the file `output` in the form of a JSON object.